# how to get the contents of <span title= with javascript and xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, title, html, imacros

ok i am very new to this. and iv been trying to figure out how to get the value of title with pure javascript and i believe xpath might work best speed wise.

```
<ul class="room_info">
    <li>
        <span>Value:</span>
        <span class="value">
            <span class="shorthand shorthand-m">
                <span title="$60,760,150,000,000,000">$60,760,150,000&nbsp;M</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
</ul>
```

this is the full xpath expression

`html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[15]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/span[2]/span/span`

what i will want to do is use imacros and this script to get the number in quotes to determine rather to click a button.
so if the number is to high it will wait until it is smaller then continue.
but right now i just need to figure out how to get the value of title.

this is the link to the page i want to run it on.
http://www.tagged.com/apps/pets.html#cashruns/3646/

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are selected with @attribute-name. In your example //span/@title might work, but you might to use a more selective xpath.

Some XPath implementations do not support attributes, so please refer to the iMacros documentation.

Comment: from what i can tell from the documentation imacros does allow for attributes with xpath. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For evaluating xpath using javascript you can use `document.evaluate()` function. You can get more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript).

```
function getSpanTitle() {
   var result = document.evaluate("//span[@class='shorthand shorthand-m']/span/@title", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);   
   var title = result.iterateNext();   
   alert(title.textContent);
}
```

Also notice that I have used relative xpath as `//span[@class='shorthand shorthand-m']/span/@title` which is more robust than absolute XPath.

Comment: Thanks for the help in the right direction... but with this i get title is null

Comment: @Justd314 This XPath works perfectly on the HTML fragment that you've provided in your question. The page where you are actully executing javascript may have different HTML structure in which case xpath needs to be modified. If you could provide me with the entire html source code or link to the page (the page you mentioned does not have element `<ul> with class room_info`), I can help you with exact xpath.

Answer (score 0):

you can scrape html tag

```
tag pos=1 type=span attr=title:* extract=htm
```

and then just extract needed data using javascript [slice() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) in [eval](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL)